# generalizing tensor flow crop and resize

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [tf.image.crop_and_resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize) functionality contains the `box_index`

```
tf.image.crop_and_resize(
    image, boxes, 
    box_ind,
    crop_size, method='bilinear', extrapolation_value=0,
    name=None)
```

We are supposed to provide the index that a particular box refers to. However, typically, image arrays are provided in the form:

```
tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), name='inp')
```

Allowing for a previously unknown number of images images to be fed into the pipeline at any time. That is a great feature that allows us to dynamically change the batch size during training and is especially useful during prediction.

However, box_index definitely does need a set of values that makes it impossible to set a variable batch size. Has anyone seen a good workaround, other than specifying a batch size manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tensor of dynamic size as box_ind like this:

```
tf.image.crop_and_resize(
    image, boxes, 
    tf.range(0, tf.shape(image)[0], dtype=tf.int32),
    crop_size, method='bilinear', extrapolation_value=0,
    name=None)
```

So each image will be cropped with corresponding box.